# Looping Audio List with React.js

Tags: reactjs, loops, audio

I am trying to self-learn React.js and I'm a bit confused about how audio list loops.

I tried to build an app that can play the sounds, but I got the issue that it cannot loop an audio list. Currently, the app randomly gets an element in the sound list and plays, I still want to the app keep going to randomly play the sound in the list until I click the stop button. But currently, it can repeat only once and I don't understand why. I did Google search but I cannot find any solution. 
Could anyone please help me with it?

Here is my attempt:

```
class PlaySound extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        play: false
      };
      // first link: 1s , second link: 7s   
      this.urls = ["https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/water/air_woosh_underwater.ogg", "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/water/drinking_from_water_fountain.ogg"];
      this.audio = new Audio(this.urls[0]);
      this.audio.addEventListener('ended', this.updateAudio.bind(this), false);
      this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
    }

    updateAudio() {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.urls.length) + 0;
        console.log(random)
        this.audio = new Audio(this.urls[random]);
        this.audio.play()
    }

    togglePlay() {
      const wasPlaying = this.state.play;
      this.setState({
        play: !wasPlaying
      });

      if (wasPlaying) {
        this.audio.pause();
      } else {
        this.audio.play()
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button
            id="audioBtn"
            onClick={this.togglePlay}> {this.state.play ? "Pause" : "Play"}
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<PlaySound />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are resetting `this.audio` in updateAudio method. I think you should bind your `'ended'` eventListener again.

Check below code

```
updateAudio() {
 const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.urls.length) + 0;
 console.log(random)
 // added below line.
 this.audio = new Audio(this.urls[random]);
 this.audio.addEventListener('ended', this.updateAudio.bind(this), false);
 this.audio.play()
}
```

Comment: Wow, it's awesome! 
Many thank.
Also, I cannot find where is the document for the audio to read.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events is the documentation ( i guess). But to your issue, the event listener 'ended' is not being fired from 2nd audio. So I felt, you should bind it in updateAudio